# How to prove $P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B) = P(A)P(B^c) - P(A\cap B^c)$?

Tags: probability, self-study

I'm trying to prove the identity in the title. I have tried all the results I'm aware of but I can't find the way out. I know that

$$P(A) = P(A\cap B)+ P(A\cap B^c),$$
and that

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B),$$

but I don't see how to combine these (or other properties I am missing) to get the desired result...

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use a [Venn Diagram](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22venn+diagram%22).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. Note that

$$
P(A)\cdot 1= P(A)(P(B)+P(B^c)) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c),
$$

and the second property is not needed here. Do you see now the way out?

Answer (score 2):

$$P(A\cap B) - P(A)P(B) = P(A)P(B^c) - P(A\cap B^c)$$
is the same statement as:$$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)(P(B)+P(B^c))$$(just replace negative terms to the other side)

or shorter:$$P(A)=P(A)$$which is evidently a true statement.